# Merge two keys of a single dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, mergeddictionaries

For a dictionary "a", with the keys "x, y and z" containing integer values.
What is the most efficient way to produce a joint list if I want to merge two keys in the dictionary (considering the size of the keys are identical and the values are of interger type)?

x+y and y+z ? .

Explanation:

Suppose you have to merge two keys and merge them into a new list or new dict without altering original dictionaries.

Example:

```
a = {"x" : {1,2,3,....,50}
     "y" : {1,2,3,.....50}
     "z" : {1,2,3,.....50}
    }
```

Desired list:

```
x+y = [2,4,6,8.....,100]
y+z = [2,4,6,......,100]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very efficient way is to do convert the dictionary to a pandas dataframe and allow it to do the job for you with its vectorized methods:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {"x" : range(1,51), "y" : range(1,51), "z" : range(1,51)}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
x_plus_y = (df['x'] + df['y']).to_list()
y_plus_z = (df['y'] + df['z']).to_list()

print(x_plus_y)
#[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100]
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it

Comment: Thank you! I did it..I am unable to upvote because of the low reputation :P

Comment: I increased your reputation by upvoting your question. You should now have the privilege.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to mimic a `join`-type operation. That is not native to python dicts, so if you really want that type of functionality, I'd recommend looking at the `pandas` library.

If you just want to merge dict keys without more advanced features, this function should help:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
from typing import Dict, List, Set, Tuple

def merge_keys(data: Dict[str, Set[int]], *merge_list: List[Tuple[str, str]]):
    merged_data = dict()
    merged_counts = Counter(list(chain(*map(lambda k: list(data.get(k, {})) if k in merge_list else [], data))))
    merged_data['+'.join(merge_list)] = [k*v for k,v in merged_counts.items()]
    return merged_data
```

You can run this with `merge_keys(a, "x", "y", "z", ...)`, where `a` is the name of your dict- you can put as many keys as you want ("x", "y", "z", ...), since this function takes a variable number of arguments.

If you want two separate merges in the same dict, all you need to do is:

```
b = merge_keys(a, "x", "y") | merge_keys(a, "y", "z")
```

Note that the order of the keys changes the final merged key ("y+z" vs "z+y") but not the value of their merged sets.

P.S: This was actually a little tricky since the original dict had set values, not lists, which aren't ordered, so you can't just add them elementwise. That's why I used `Counter` here, in case you were wondering.

Comment: Thank you for the technique.